# Combining a local source and remote source in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I included locally in javascript a list of commonly used terms, and then I would also like to get json response from the server through ajax response. How can it be done?

```
var projects = ["apple", "orange"];

$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: projects
});
```

then append the result from ajax?

Comment: In other words, if a local result doesn't exist, make an AJAX call? Or do you always want to make an AJAX call?

Comment: Actually in any case make the ajax call, sequentially. In other words, if you have two sources, and you don't do the combination on server side, is there a way to combine the result from the two sources via javascript?

Comment: Yes, there is. I think I have enough information to post an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you would go about this would be to combine the results you get back from the server with the local results array. You can accomplish this by passing a function to the `source` option of autocomplete:

There are three steps you'll have to perform:

1. Make the AJAX request and get results from the server.
2. Filter the local array
3. Combine the results

This should be pretty simple. Something like this would work:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) { 
        /* local results: */
        var localResults = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(localArray, request.term);

        /* Remote results: */
        $.ajax({
            /* AJAX options omitted... */
            success: function(data) {
                /* Process remote data using $.map, if necessary, then concatenate local
                 * and remote results. 
                 */
                response(data.concat(localResults));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've worked up a full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/FZ4N4/

Comment: What if you want to show the local results and then append the remote results once they are available?

Comment: Well I feel stupid. You just call response() again with the new results.