# JSON not returning results in jsfiddle /echo/json/ autocomplete demo, only in console

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, jsfiddle

I took a jsfiddle example that is doing what I need with a local array of data, and tried to make it work from remote data using jsfiddles method.

Here is the first jsfiddle with the ability to type multiple "tags" in the 
http://jsfiddle.net/T45rQ/8/

```
var tags = [
    "example.com"
    ,"akamai.com"
    ,"2charts.com"
    ,"gmail.com"
    ,"jquery.com"
    ,"yahoo.com"
    ,"ymail.com"
    ,"hotmail.com"
];

results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, term);
```

Here is the same attempt to have the same displayed but with a remote data source - this is updated with the correct JSON format after @dc5 pointed out an error.
http://jsfiddle.net/T45rQ/138/

```
var data = 'json=[{"label":"example.com","value":"example.com"},{"label":"akamai.com","value":"akamai.com"},{"label":"2charts.com","value":"2charts.com"},{"label":"gmail.com","value":"gmail.com"},{"label":"jquery.com","value":"jquery.com"},{"label":"yahoo.com","value":"yahoo.com"},{"label":"ymail.com","value":"ymail.com"},{"label":"hotmail.com","value":"hotmail.com"}]'

             results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                     $.ajax({
                         url:"/echo/json/",
                         data:data,
                         type:"POST",
                         success:function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            response
                         }
                     })
                     , term);
```

There was a problem with the data at first, but @dc5 commented below and pointed out the JSON error. Now we only need to get the drop-down functionality to show up, even though the results show up in the console and no errors seem to be generated.

Once the results are working, I can ultimately test if the functionality is working like before which is the ultimate goal.

Comment: I think its typo in `var data = 'json={"label":"example.com","label":"jquery.com","label":"yahoo.com"}'`

Comment: You have multiple "label" keys - a self respecting JSON interpreter will throw out all but the last one.  You also have an extra ending `}` in your json string.  It's likely the json string should be `'json=[…]'`

Comment: If the first example works, shouldn't you just be returning a simple array that looks something like this: `'["example.com", "akamai.com", …]'`? (a parsed version)

Comment: Maybe this post will help: [Combining a local source and remote source in jquery ui autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043608/combining-a-local-source-and-remote-source-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Comment: 1. `var data = { json: '[{"label":"example.com","value":"example.com"} ...' };` 2. You have to call response callback in source function `success: function (res) { console.log(res); response(res); } }`